# Drupal 7: How to create a text field with php default value?

Tags: php, drupal-7, cck, textfield, default-value

I've been searching for quite a while now and still wasn't able to find an answer yet.

I'm using Drupal 7.4 and I created a new content type. There i want to add a simple text field that has a Default value where I can add PHP. Normally, the Default value shows only plain text.

To be more specific:
For the users I defined a field_city that they must complete when they sign up.
So for example i would have a user "john" from "Bucharest".
I need to assign the value of field_city - namely Bucharest - to the default value of the text field via PHP (I know how to do this part).
So when john adds new content, he would already have Bucharest printed in that text field but still be able to write whatever other city there.

How could I achieve this?
Can I get away without making a custom module?
Thanx.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to do, is there another way you can explain it?

Comment: So i go to Administration>>Structure and i click on Add content type.

Comment: So i go to Administration>>Structure and i click on Add content type. After i have created my brand new content type i go to "Manage fields">>Add new field. From -Select a field type- i choose "text" and from -Select widget- i click on the only available option "Text field". Then "save". After that i have to select the settings for the text field. A bit down the page i have "Default value
The default value for this field, used when creating new content." What i need to do is address this "default value" via PHP, since one can only enter plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the CCK module for Drupal 7? Although it is still in development status, it will do the trick.